# General Information

Tags: smart-contracts, contract

I know tezos strongly believes in immutability but I would like to clear out some curiosity regarding upgradability of a contract.

1. If a function in a contract needs to be updated with it's logic , how can we do that?
2. If we want to add a new function in an already originated contract, Is it possible or do we need to deploy a whole new contract ?
3. How do we handle bugs if we get some issue in mainnet contract ? How are other product of tezos handling this ? Are there any example where a mainnet contract gets an issue and how was that issue handled?
4. Is there any concept like OpenZeppelin(tools for deploying upgradeable smart contracts in solidity) in tezos ?

Looking forward for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1,2. This is done by storing a lambda in a map/big_map and then calling it from the entry-point. That way you can update the logic of the entry point by storing another lambda.
- 3. You should create a mechanism to handle this. (e.i. make the contract pausable)
- 4. Yes, it is called [lazy entry-points](https://smartpy.io/docs/introduction/entrypoints/#lazy-entrypoints) in smartpy. Here is also an example in [ligo](https://gitlab.com/ligolang/ligo/-/blob/dev/gitlab-pages/docs/tutorials/optimisation/examples/contracts/ligo/large_entrypoint/LargeEntrypointV2.ligo).

I am of the opinion that most contract's code should be final once they get deployed. Using a proxy approach is almost always preferable.

Comment: 2. How does storing lambda in a map/big_map helps in creating a entirely new function in a contract, here i am mentioning a new feature that will be written in a new function not in existing function. Is there any example?
3. How can we resolve the issue after making the contract pausable.
4. Do you have any example?

Comment: 2. The lambda contains the body of the function. You cannot update the function signature. 3. Pointing to a new contract in the proxy contract or updating the lambda, depending on the approach you use. 4. Adding to the examples already provided above https://smartpy.io/ide?template=lazy_entry_points.py